# Django QuerySet selecting rows according a 'valid_from' column

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model with date dependent product prices similar to this:

```
Class ProductPrice(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='prices')
    valid_from = models.DateField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
```

The 'valid_from' dates can be past and future.

If I would need the valid price for a single product on 'some_date' it would be simple:

```
price = product.prices.filter(valid_from__lte=some_date).latest('valid_from')
```

However, I need a list with all prices for a given date.
How can I get a QS that selects the valid price for all (or a set of) products für a certain date?

EG, widgets cost $3 each starting September 1 2017, but will cost $4 each starting October 4 2017. If asked for the price on September 11 2017, it needs to find the $3 value - the example latest() query does that for a single product, but the question is how to do this for multiple products. Latest on a set of prices grouped by product, basically.
Thanks @PeterDeGlopper for the example!

Comment: When I implemented a similar pattern on a past project, I also used a nullable `end_date` field to support this kind of query. Is revising the model to include something like that an option for you?

Comment: That would work (like an sql select between), but it would need a whole mechanism for automaticly setting the 'end_date'. I would prefer not having to do that...

Comment: I did it with post-save signals, IIRC - any time the price model is saved, set any old records with a null end date to end on the start date of the new one. It does seem like something the database should be able to answer for you.

Comment: Yes, I'll probably end-up doing it this way. Still, it's a pitty the Django ORM doesn't provide a native solution.

Comment: Possibly you could do it with a database view, the ORM has no problem treating views as if they were read-only models.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
prices = ProductPrice.objects.filter(valid_from=GIVEN_DATE).values_list('price')
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants the latest price that has not yet been superceded, not just ones that become effective on the specified day. EG, widgets cost $3 each starting September 1 2017, but will cost $4 each starting October 4 2017. If asked for the price on September 11 2017, it needs to find the $3 value - the example `latest()` query does that for a single product, but the question is how to do this for multiple products. Latest on a set of prices grouped by product, basically, but I don't remember if the Django aggregation API makes that easy to express.

Comment: Thanks @PeterDeGlopper for your explanation of my problem! :-)